# How to prove that two data models are logically equivalent?

Tags: database, database-design

Suppose Alice has a data model:

```
Person: {
    id: int (unique not null),
    name: string,
    phone_number: string
}
```

Bob suggests that Alice could also use the following data model:

```
Person: {
    id: int (unique not null),
    name: string
}

Number: {
    person_id: int (fk Person(id) not null),
    phone_number: string
}
```

Alice asks Bob "are the two models equivalent?"

In theory, a single string field could store arbitrary data, so in some sense both Alice's and Bob's models could model *anything*, and thus Alice can store Bob's data and vice versa.  This doesn't feel like a very satisfactory notion of the two models being equivalent.

In general, what are some useful definitions of formal logical/semantic "equivalence" between data models, and how can we determine that two data models are equivalent?

Comment: Define "store all of the data that's already in" & "model at least all of the data that the old data model could model" & "two data models are logically equivalent" (& "two data models are non-logically equivalent"). If you don't know what you mean by that & you are wondering how to formalize some vague notion(s), edit to ask that question with whatever properties you can think of to determine such an "equivalence". PS  [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Comment: A "data model" is a model for data, like the relational model, for modelling the data of something. A particular DB design under a particular data model is a DB design. (But "model" does get used to mean "design".)

Comment: DB normalization to higher NFs does not introduce new column names, it replaces a base table by others that are projections of it that natural join to it. The suggested "normalization" is a normalization plus column renaming. What role do renamings have in your notion of "equivalent" ("models")? Constraints tell the DBMS that certain DB states are legal/illegal. They don't record data. What role do DB constraints play in your notion of "equivalent" designs ("models")? PS Please ask just 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question, via 1 question mark. [ask] [Help]

Comment: [Re what a DB & its constraints "say" to the user & DBMS.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24909854/3404097)

Comment: @philipxy "What role do constraints play in your notion of 'equivalence'?" This is a fair question.  I had hoped that there were "ordinary" notions of "equivalence" in data modeling, and that I would learn something about that theough an answer to the question...

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Delete & flag obsolete comments. PS You use a word knowing that you don't mean anything by it? Don't write stuff that doesn't mean anything to you. Like I said if you want to ask about formalizing something you have a vague notion about do that. And it's hard to know what to write about one's vague notion. But be clear that what you are writing is trying to capture something you are unclear about. And don't write things that don't mean anything to you. PS Scare quotes don't make things clear when you didn't actually say what you meant (if anything).

Comment: The scare quotes I was referring to were the ones in `"ordinary"` in your comment.

Comment: @philipxy exactly.  I'm not an expert in database design, but it is my understanding that at least relational database design is based around first-order logic.  In first-order logic, we can talk about two structures being "equivalent" in a number of ways that one might consider "ordinary" (but "ordinary" is not the formal term).  One can prove that two structures are equivalent in one way, but not in another, for example.  I do not know if these concepts map to database design, so attempting to be more specific I think would be confusing or more likely simply wrong.

Comment: You keep using words--normalize, logically, semantically, equivalent--that do not have specific meanings in this context. Moreover you have said that YOU don't even have a specific meaning in this context for 'equivalent'. Stop. Use words that you know have a meaning shared with readers. If you don't know exactly what you want then go brainstorm to come up with something clear & specific & precise that you can communicate to other people & apply. (But this isn't a site for that.)

Comment: There might be on-topic questions along the lines of "What is a formal statement of some reasonable notion of 2 DBs recording the same things about the business situation--that we could hence reasonably call 'equivalence')?" Or "What is a common specific DB definition of such equivalence?" (There isn't one.) But using words that don't mean anything in particular as if they did is not going to produce that question. There are certainly reasonable definitions & demonstrations of such equivalence. Giving a definition & designs & asking how to get unstuck determining equivalence could be on-topic.

Comment: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate on-topic question. PS [Why was my "shopping list" question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/266284)

Comment: @philipxy yes.  I have done that.  Are you suggesting that a notion of "equivalence" and a way to determine "equivalence" are two separate questions?  IMHO any definition of "equivalence" necessarily defines the conditions that must be met for two structures to be "equivalent".  Also, is there a duplicate?  If you are aware of one, please suggest it.  Or did you mean that "Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?" is a duplicate of this?  I must admit that I don't immediately see the connection...

Comment: "are the two models equivalent?" -- No. Alice's model allows a single phone number per person, while Bob's model allows multiple phone numbers per person.

Comment: @TheImpaler excellent.  Does this concept generalize?  Does your distinction between Alice's and Bob's models have a formalization (i.e. a definition of "equivalence"), and how can we use that formalization to check if two models are "equivalent"?

Comment: @TheImpaler There are unlimited ways they are equivalent because one just has to define an equivalence relation. The question already talks about that with its arbitrary encodings. Your saying they are or are not equivalent is per an equivalence relation you have not given--albeit probably a sensible one. This begs the question--what (sort of things) does the asker have in mind & what are "sensible" equivalence relations. But a discussion or exploration or enumeration is not on-topic. One could write a precis on the topic but it isn't suitable for a Q&A site. A part of one could be suitable.

Comment: @philipxy Yeah, I agree. I was just trying to point out a simple difference when reverse engineering a physical database model, without having the formal design.

Comment: [How to show that something increases relational expressive power?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27085220/3404097)

Comment: The canonical theoretical foundation for relational algebra indeed is set-theoretic, so your question IMO does have a point and a precise answer. -- If that sounds interesting/useful, I could try and put together an answer with some explanation and possibly a concrete application to your example.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio yes, this is precisely what I was hoping for.  Do you think it would be more useful to cross-post this question on a different StackExchange site that supports LaTeX formatting?

Comment: Is cross-posting allowed at all?  I am relatively new to SO, so others will have to help on that side.  --  I think I could do with some ASCII notation then (pseudo-)code, it's not a very deep theoretical treatment I'd have in mind anyway, just enough to get to the point: but I'd have to start putting together an actual answer to be sure about it.  I will anyway, I might have a draft by tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In general, what are some useful definitions of formal logical/semantic "equivalence" between data models, and how can we determine that two data models are equivalent?

To begin with, relational algebra is most naturally, and most canonically, modelled set-theoretically and at first order: a relation is *a set of tuples so and so*, then there exist operations such as projection and join.  (It is not plain set theory, where everything is a set and sets contain sets, and in many ways it is simpler/more restricted than plain set theory, but I will delegate to the papers linked below for a formal treatment.)

That said, in so far as *equivalence* is a defined notion, the answer to any equivalence question in general depends on the specific definition in use.  On the other hand, any such definition is not totally arbitrary: as a minimum it shall satisfy the criteria that make it an *equivalence relation*.  Moreover, leveraging the *intensional* (or *nominal*) vs *extensional* distinction, we can define, and ask questions of, identity and/or equivalence along a range with essentially two extremes (two poles): intensional (aka nominal) is exact equality by name, not just shape; extensional is equivalence of content / of data (as in two sets are "equal" if they contain the same elements), namely, two relations are equivalent if they represent the same set of tuples.

That is still informal and not totally precise (again, I will have to delegate to more formal treatment), but for an intuitive understanding of the nominal vs extensional distinction, consider this basic example: are the following tables "equivalent"?

```
CatTypes {
  ID     auto  PK 
  Title  text  UK
  Order  int   IX
}
```

```
ItemTypes {
  ID       auto  PK 
  Name     text  UK
  Sorting  int   IX
}
```

It should be obvious that, from a strictly nominal point of view, they just aren't (even just the table name changing makes them different: and they indeed are different, at least potentially, at some semantic level); while, from an extensional point of view, **it should be apparent that they express exactly the same structure and constraints, and in that sense they do are equivalent**.
Eventually, it might also be apparent how the notion of equivalence that in our case is relevant, e.g. to prove correctness of schema and query transformations, rather is *the extensional one*: in other words, we are *not* dealing with semantics here.

And now I delegate to more formal treatment:

Searching with keywords "equivalence relational schema", I have found two technical papers (and not much more), luckily both freely available, on the specific problem of model / schema equivalence.  Notice that their definition of equivalence indeed is an *extensional* one in the sense I have sketched above: simply put, **two models / schemas are equivalent if they (can) represent the same data**.

###### [Equivalence of relational database schemes (1979)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/800135.804424)

Here is the Abstract:

<< We investigate the question of when two database schemes embody the same information. We argue that this question reduces to the equivalence of the sets of fixed points of the project-join mappings associated with the two database schemes in question. When data dependencies are given, we need only consider those fixed points that satisfy the dependencies. A polynomial algorithm to test the equivalence of database schemes, when there are no dependencies, is given. We also provide an exponential algorithm to handle the case where there are functional and/or multivalued dependencies. Furthermore, we give a polynomial time test to determine whether a project-join mapping preserves a set of functional dependencies, and a polynomial time algorithm for equivalence of database schemes whose project-join mappings do preserve the given set of functional dependencies. Lastly, we introduce the "update sets" approach to database design as an application of these results. >>

###### [Inclusion and equivalence between relational database schemata (1982)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(82)90038-X)

Excerpts from the Introduction:

<< In order to formalize these comparisons and relationships there is the need of precise definitions of conceptual relations among database schemata, that is, relations that compare the ability of database schemata to represent information and answer to queries. >>

<< The main characteristics of our approach are:

- to base the comparison of database schemata on the ability to answer queries;
- to consider not only vertical transformations but also horizontal and even more general ones;
- to establish a framework in which database schemata may be compared both when the existence of the universal relation is assumed and when it is not;
- to allow the comparison of database schemata in which any kind of integrity constraint can be defined. >>

[I am sure my answer can be improved, it is more of a first approximation: I will look forward to any feedback/suggestions/objections.]

Comment: Thanks for the citations.  The Beeri et al 1979 looks particularly relevant.  I am working on an applied project needing to ingest data from various schemas into a single schema, and it's not always immediately apparent if such a thing is possible without loss of data.